# Solidity keccak behavior

Tags: solidity, keccak, encoding

I have a weird issue. I'm trying to keccak256 packed encoded arguments in Rust [which should mimic Soldity's behavior to be checked on chain later]. I've failed for now. To figure out the issue I've been writing a small test contract with the following functions:

```
    function doKeccak(bytes memory _data) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(_data);
    }

    function packed(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value,
        bytes memory _data,
        uint256 _nonce,
        uint256 _gasPrice,
        uint256 _gasLimit
    ) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return
            abi.encodePacked(
                bytes1(0x19),
                bytes1(0),
                _from,
                _to,
                _value,
                _data,
                _nonce,
                _gasPrice,
                _gasLimit
            );
    }

   function doKeccakPacked(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value,
        bytes memory _data,
        uint256 _nonce,
        uint256 _gasPrice,
        uint256 _gasLimit
    ) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    bytes1(0x19),
                    bytes1(0),
                    _from,
                    _to,
                    _value,
                    _data,
                    _nonce,
                    _gasPrice,
                    _gasLimit
                )
            );
    }
```

Now, from the rust program if I call [pseudo-code] `contract.doKeccakPacked(args..)` and `contract.doKeccak(contract.packed(args))` I get different results ...

Any idea ?

**Edit**
Here is, for instance, a raw Rust params array, which leads to different results:

```
[
    Address(
        0xdfa1468d07fc86840a6eb53e0e65cebde81d1af9,
    ),
    Address(
        0x7f114fc87edc5f1311d4e77d1a3018a3dc34f47e,
    ),
    Uint(
        0,
    ),
    Bytes(
        [
            201,
            13,
            180,
            71,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            127,
            17,
            79,
            200,
            126,
            220,
            95,
            19,
            17,
            212,
            231,
            125,
            26,
            48,
            24,
            163,
            220,
            52,
            244,
            126,
        ],
    ),
    Uint(
        94481061581245121,
    ),
    Uint(
        0,
    ),
    Uint(
        250000,
    ),
]
```

**Edit 2**

Here is the rust code:

```
fn hash_sign(
        &self,
        wallet: Address,
        data: ethabi::Bytes,
        nonce: U256,
    ) -> Result<Bytes, String> {
        let options = Options::default();

        // this is the contract whose test functions are above
        let erc_1077_hash_abi = ethabi::Contract::load(constants::abis::ERC1077_HASH).unwrap();
        let erc_1077_hash_address = Address::from_str(&"83649266Ba0a8CAd860403a6532F12c6074BBDAC").unwrap();

        let function = erc_1077_hash_abi.function("doKeccakPacked").unwrap();
        let params: [ethabi::Token; 7] = [
            ethabi::Token::Address(self.address),
            ethabi::Token::Address(wallet),
            ethabi::Token::Uint(self.value()),
            ethabi::Token::Bytes(data.clone()),
            ethabi::Token::Uint(nonce),
            ethabi::Token::Uint(self.gas_price()),
            ethabi::Token::Uint(self.gas_limit()),
        ];

        let encoded = function.encode_input(&params).unwrap();
        let result_1 = self.web3.eth().call(
            CallRequest {
                from: None,
                to: erc_1077_hash_address,
                gas: options.gas,
                gas_price: options.gas_price,
                value: options.value,
                data: Some(Bytes(encoded)),
            },
            None.into(),
        );

        let result_1 = match result_1.wait() {
          Ok(s) => Ok(s),
          Err(_e) => Err(format!("error")),
      };

        let function = erc_1077_hash_abi.function("packed").unwrap();
        let encoded = function.encode_input(&params).unwrap();

        let packed = self.web3.eth().call(
            CallRequest {
                from: None,
                to: erc_1077_hash_address,
                gas: options.gas,
                gas_price: options.gas_price,
                value: options.value,
                data: Some(Bytes(encoded.clone())),
            },
            None.into(),
        );

        let packed = packed.wait().unwrap();
        let packed = packed.0;

        let function = erc_1077_hash_abi.function("doKeccak").unwrap();
        let params: [ethabi::Token; 1] = [
            ethabi::Token::Bytes(packed),
        ];
        let encoded = function.encode_input(&params).unwrap();

        let result_2 = self.web3.eth().call(
            CallRequest {
                from: None,
                to: erc_1077_hash_address,
                gas: options.gas,
                gas_price: options.gas_price,
                value: options.value,
                data: Some(Bytes(encoded)),
            },
            None.into(),
        );

        let result_2 = match result_2.wait() {
          Ok(s) => Ok(s),
          Err(_e) => Err(format!("error")),
      };


        result_1
    }
```

Here result_1 and result_2 are differents ...

Comment: `x19` does not compile.

Comment: `packed` is not a function.

Comment: Other than that (i.e., after fixing these trivial errors), I tested your code and it returns the exact same values. Please provide an example set of arguments which gives a different result.

Comment: Hi, yeah sorry for the typo. I've tested it from Rust [not js] and results do not match.

You can `set` to and `from` to whatever - different - addresses you want, `gasPrice` to 0, `gasLimit` to 250000, `nonce` to 35681459843, `value` to 0 and data to whatever bytes array.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I didn't say how **I** tested it, and again - please provide an example set of arguments which gives a different result for each method.

Comment: Both methods give `0x0177d9769a8b94793c80829f3f06cc1b0c4a8af2baa310a3aaf1e1de2bb5c339` when executed via web3.js. The problem is therefore in your Rust code, which you haven't posted here.

Comment: Thanks ! Just posted the Rust code.

Comment: What are the values of your `result_1` and `result_2` then?

Comment: Result 1 `Bytes([225, 159, 4, 121, 196, 66, 68, 97, 86, 92, 240, 89, 16, 136, 162, 113, 139, 45, 213, 251, 50, 104, 132, 113, 45, 97, 235, 73, 104, 93, 103, 246])
`

Result 2 `Bytes([118, 108, 71, 63, 139, 231, 84, 196, 191, 5, 187, 17, 35, 48, 108, 175, 106, 227, 68, 184, 210, 164, 110, 155, 116, 48, 13, 101, 79, 59, 73, 228])`

Comment: I've referred to the example which you had posted in the (now deleted) self-answer below. Please reinstate that example into your question here, and then post again the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out. It was not a `keccak` issue but a problem related to the way the `web3` rust crate decode bytes data returned from the chain. It enforces some weird padding - turning it into a `FixedBytes` type - thus messing up with the whole workflow.

Thanks everyone.